# How to post Raw body data with content-Type JSON(application/json) in React Fetch Blob

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i try post in Postman with Raw body data and "JSON(application/json)" like this

[image]

success uploaded. but, in react-native-fetch-blob with code below still failed

this is the code

```
var dataToServer = [];
  dataToServer.push({ name : 'permit_list_id', data : '4'});
  dataToServer.push({ name : 'items[0][item_id]', data : '16'});
  dataToServer.push({ name : 'items[0][answer]', data : '1'});

    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'https://urlPost', {

    'Authorization' : tokenJSON.access,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
  }, dataToServer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the `RNFetchBlob.fetch` method, you shall use `JSON.stringify(dataToServer)` instead of `dataToServer`. (posted data should be a JSON-string instead of an object)

And also I think in your code `dataToServer` is an `Array` instead of an `Object` (as in the screenshot you provided). I suggest you verify the content of `dataToServer` by `console.log(dataToServer);` before sending it.